# How to return the last matching condition row per group?

Tags: r, group-by, tail

I am working on a file with many machinas. Each machina works during a cycle (which goes from -1 to -1) and I have some operation parameters:

1: High power operation
0.5: Low power operation
0: No operation
-1: End of operation

I have a list of my machinas consisting of these kind of dataframe (one per machina - this one is a really small sample) :

```
    *Indx*  *N°1 Operation*  *N°1 Operation length*
       1           1                450
       1          0.5                84
       1           0                 48
       1           1                  4
       1          0.5                 4
       1           1                123
       1          0.5                14
       1          -1                 45
       2           1                471
       2           0                 47
       2          0.5                44
       2           0                145
       2          0.5                78
       2           1                 71
       2          0.5                19
       2           0                  2
       2          -1                 45
```

I would like to get for each group the last row with 1 value (high power operation). My purpose is then to sum the lengths from this last High operation value to end of cycle.

Desired output :

```
*Indx*    *N°1 Operation length*
  1                  123+14
  2                  71+19+2
```

How can I get to that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` one way is to `filter` the End of operation rows from the data, `group_by` `Indx` and `sum` the `Operation2` values which occur between last occurrence when `Operation1` is 1 till the last row. We find the last occurrence of 1 using `cumsum` value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Operation1 != -1) %>%
  group_by(Indx) %>%
  summarise(Oplength = sum(Operation2[cumsum(Operation1 == 1) == 
                                  max(cumsum(Operation1 == 1))]))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Indx Oplength
#  <int>    <int>
#1     1      137
#2     2       92
```

---

Or another way to find last occurrence is using `which` and `max`

```
df %>%
  filter(Operation1 != -1) %>%
  group_by(Indx) %>%
  summarise(Oplength = sum(Operation2[max(which(Operation1 == 1)) : n()]))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Indx = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Operation1 = c(1, 0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 
1, 0.5, -1, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, -1), Operation2 = c(450L, 
84L, 48L, 4L, 4L, 123L, 14L, 45L, 471L, 47L, 44L, 145L, 78L, 
71L, 19L, 2L, 45L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work ! But I cannot find Oplength, and it does not want to mutate. However I can see the good tibble on the console... Do you know why ?

Comment: @AliciaBassiere Maybe you need to assign the result back? `df1 <- df %>%
  filter(Operation1 != -1) %>%
  group_by(Indx) %>%
  summarise(Oplength = sum(Operation2[max(which(Operation1 == 1)) : n()]))` and check `df1` now.

Answer (score 0):

In base R we could do

```
do.call(rbind, by(d, d[[1]], function(x) 
  c(Indx=x[[1]][1], 
    N.1.Operation.length=sum(x[[3]][head(max(which(x[[2]] > .5)):nrow(x), -1)]))))
#   Indx N.1.Operation.length
# 1    1                  137
# 2    2                   92
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(Indx = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), N.1.Operation = c(1, 0.5, 0, 1, 
0.5, 1, 0.5, -1, 1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, -1), N.1.Operation.length = c(450L, 
84L, 48L, 4L, 4L, 123L, 14L, 45L, 471L, 47L, 44L, 145L, 78L, 
71L, 19L, 2L, 45L)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```